# Polyfill to list the HTTP headers of a Header's instance

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-browser, http-headers, fetch-api

Certain versions¹ of Firefox support `Headers` but lack `Headers.prototype.entries` and `Headers.prototype.forEach`⁴.

How to go through all key/value pairs of a `Headers`' instance in an ES5-compatible² and elegant³ way on these browsers?
Could `Headers` be extended?

<sub>¹ 34–43

² no for…of

³ no brute force

⁴ supported since version 47</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Firefox 44 (which added `.keys/entries/values` on `Headers`), there was no non-brute-force way to find out what set of headers were actually set in the object.  The information simply isn't exposed anywhere.

That said, releases prior to Firefox 45 (the current ESR release) are all out of support and have known security bugs, so users should *really* not be using those.  I don't think it's worth catering to users on those releases; they should be urged to update instead.

Comment: I wanted to upvote but I completely disagree on your upgrading stance which negates any effort towards backward compatibility.

Comment: I'm all in favor of backwards compatibility when it's feasible.  In this case it really isn't, very much, unfortunately.